# Cómo el algoritmo funciona al obtener las raices?

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

Sé que es el método newton-raphson para obtener las raíces y que en esto está involucrado el cálculo, y aunque no tengo conocimiento del cálculo,

Cómo realmente llega a sacar la raíz de un número ?
He leído que la función es de la forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con que `n`, debe ser un número cercano al número al cual se le quiere sacar la raiz, y que `f'` es la derivada, esto posiblemente está más orientado al foro matemático, pero aún así, ahí no podrán hablarme de código.

Lo extraño que si el `n`, lo cambio por otro valor más grande, según lo que leí deberia darme una raíz diferente porque `diverge`, pero qué es tal cosa?

Además me gustaría que me recomendaran, para entender este tipo de cosas, algún libro en español, posiblemente será de cálculo, pero por favor en cuenta que aún no entro a la educación superior.

Es dificil publicar este tipo de cosas en el foro matemático, son bastante póco sutiles con la gente que no sabe y desea aprender, agradecería la ayuda para seguir aprendiendo.

```js
var radicando = 2;
var resultado = 99;
var i = 0;

while(i<25){
resultado=resultado-((resultado*resultado-radicando)/(2*resultado));
i++;
}
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: ¿Conoces el concepto de pendiente?

Comment: Lo que he visto en geometría son cónicas y la recta, y lo que se, es que la pendiente es la inclinacion de la recta respecto al eje x

Comment: Okay, para figuras sencillas como rectas o que tengan un perfil similar este es calculado como `m = dy/dx` donde dy = es la variacion de y y dx es la variacion de x para un intervalo en particular ya que por ejemplo para la recta es constante esta cantidad

Comment: pero para curvas en general que llamaramos suaves esta pendiente es variante, y un método para calcularlo es a traves de las derivadas, es decir la pendiente `m = f'(x)`, no quiero profundizar en este tema ya que como comentas no tienes conocimientos de cálculo.

Comment: entonces como ves esa pendiente solo depende de la curva y un punto en particular, por ejemplo si `f(x) = x^3` entonces su derivada es `f'(x)=3x^2`, y asi podemos obtener mediante cálculo o tablas las derivadas de diversas expresiones.

Comment: gracias por darte el tiempo eyllanesc, supongo que para entender esta funcion necesito conocer el cálculo, recomiendas algún(os) libros?

Comment: Para una pequeña region se puede decir que la derivada es constante ya que varia poco(a eso me referia con suave), y entonces podemos usar la formula que menciones, `f'(x) = dy/dx`,  ademas sabemos que una raiz `x0` cumple que `f(x0) = 0`, podemos hacer la siguiente simplificación: `f'(x1) = (f(x1)-f(x0))/(x1-x0)`, reemplazando la condicion anterior:  `f'(x1) = (f(x1))/(x1-x0)`, y despejando:  `x1-x0 = f(x1)/f'(x1)`, y al final `x0=x1-f(x1)/f'(x1)`, obviamente falta demostrar que la serie converge, pero para ello necesitamos de cálculo. Cualquier libro te servira ya que eres un novato.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian ya miraste video en youtube?? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX9ecFstUUk

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el **método de Steffensen** (por Johan Frederik Steffensen) es un algoritmo para obtener los ceros de una función.

El método de Steffensen se puede considerar como una combinación del método de punto fijo y del método de Aitken.

Como el método de Aitken esencialmente acelera la convergencia de otro método, se puede definir este método como el método de punto fijo acelerado.

En *Matlab* el código sería el siguiente:

```
function [x,i,tolf]=steffensen(x0,f,tolx,nmax) 
       err=tolx+1; 
    x=x0; 
    phi=0; 
    while(i<nmax & err>tolx) 
        xx=x; 
        fxk=feval(f,x); 
        tolf=tolx*abs(phi); 
        if abs(fxk)<=tolf 
            break 
        end     
        fxk2=feval(f,x+fxk);
        phi=(fxk2-fxk)/fxk; 
        x=xx-fxk/phi; 
        err=abs(x-xx);
        i=i+1; 
    end
```